# Cannot add Service layer to Orchard site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac, orchardcms

I am trying to add a service project into my Orchard CMS site but when I inject that service into my controller I get this error:

```
 Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Orchard.Environment.AutofacUtil.DynamicProxy2.ConstructorFinderWrapper' on type 'tiko23867.SharedUI.Controllers.ContactUsController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Autofac.ContainerBuilder builder' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Autofac.ContainerBuilder, Services.ContactUs.IContactUsService)'.
```

I have looked up questions on stack overflow but those problems that involve this error seem to be with freshly installing Orchard.

My controller :

```
using BusinessObjects.ContactUs;
using Orchard.Themes;
using Services.ContactUs;
using tiko23867.SharedUI.Models;

namespace tiko23867.SharedUI.Controllers
{
    [Themed]
    public partial class ContactUsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IContactUsService _contactUsService;

        public ContactUsController(IContactUsService contactUsService)
        {
            _contactUsService = contactUsService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public virtual ActionResult Index()
        {
            var viewModel = new ContactUsViewModel();

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult Index(ContactUsViewModel contactUsViewModel)
        {
            _contactUsService.SaveContactUsRequest(new ContactUsItem
            {
                Email = contactUsViewModel.Email,
                FirstName = contactUsViewModel.FirstName,
                LastName = contactUsViewModel.LastName,
                Message = contactUsViewModel.Message
            });

            return View("Thanks");
        }

    }
}
```

My Service:

```
using BusinessObjects.ContactUs;

namespace Services.ContactUs
{
    public interface IContactUsService
    {
        void SaveContactUsRequest(ContactUsItem item);
    }

    public class ContactUsService
    {
        public ContactUsService()
        {
        }

        public void SaveContactUsRequest(ContactUsItem item)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify - did you intend your service implementation to be an Autofac module? It looks like it should be a separate class. Not entirely sure but I could imagine you might get some funky issues when an Autofac module is itself a dependency on some class.

Comment: Let me just remove that then.

Comment: Does removing it affect the behaviour / error or is the edited version already what you were running?

Comment: Removing it is does not affect the behavior sadly :(

Comment: It's difficult to comment further without a more complete set of code to look at, it seems likely that it's related to something outside of just the classes above, potentially where your registration are. Aside from that, I know you've said you've looked and it's not 100% the same scenario, but do any of the suggestions here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807938/error-none-of-the-constructors-found-with-orchard-environment-autofacutil-dyn ? Seems like orchard may be masking an inner error showing exactly which dependency is missing.

Comment: So I removed that code and then it is now working. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make your interface inherit from `IDependency`, which will automatically register your service and make it discoverable via constructor injection. No need to mess around with autofac.